# Typeclass implicit not found when caller has parametrized value

Tags: scala, typeclass

EDIT: I've removed my overcomplicated example that only obfuscated the problem for a simple one

I'm trying to figure out how to provide the necessary evidence to a typeclass using method for which one parameter generic, but can should be determinable from context

```
trait Converter[A, B] {
  def apply(a: A, b: B): String
}

object Converters {

  implicit object DoubleIntConverter extends Converter[Double, Int] {
    override def apply(a: Double, b: Int): String = a.toString + ":" + b.toString
  }

  implicit object IntIntConverter extends Converter[Int, Int] {
    override def apply(a: Int, b: Int): String = a.toString + ":" + b.toString
  }

}

// passing in an Int
println(fun1(1))

// calling fun2 with Int and Int
def fun1[A](a: A) = fun2(a, 42)

def fun2[A, B](a: A, b: B)(implicit converter: Converter[A, B]): String = converter(a, b)
```

The error i get is:

```
Error:(36, 49) could not find implicit value for parameter converter: Converter[A,Int]
def fun1[A](a: A)(implicit arg: Arg[A]) = fun2(a, 42)
                                   ^
Error:(36, 49) not enough arguments for method fun2: (implicit converter: Converter[A,Int])String.
  Unspecified value parameter converter.
def fun1[A](a: A)(implicit arg: Arg[A]) = fun2(a, 42)
                                   ^
```

`fun2` doesn't know what `A` is. In this example, from the use of `fun1` `A` is clearly an `Int` and `B` is also an `Int` and there exists an implicit object `IntIntConverter`. I assumed that problem is that `A` could be anything at all even not in the compiled code.

So I tried constraining `A` to `Int` or `Double` so that the `Converter` could be exhaustively enumerated with another typeclass:

```
sealed trait Arg[T]

object Arg {

  implicit object IntArg extends Arg[Int]

  implicit object DoubleArg extends Arg[Double]
}

def fun1[A](a: A)(implicit arg: Arg[A]) = fun2(a, 42)
```

The error now complains that here is not `Converter[A,Int]` at `fun1` and I tried various other implicit variations, but I cannot get `Converter` to recognize the constraint imposed by `Arg` and therefore can never find an implicit for itself.

Is there some way to define this so that`fun2` can have a generic parameter but have it be able to determine which implementation of `Converter` it needs to include?

Comment: If static analysis can tell you that's the only possible type, then your code can do so too. Your code is very long and unclear to me. The comments to `fun1` say you don't know the input type? In that case, how can you know that there's a suitable `TransformerSource` for that input/output pair? Or do you want to claim that there's something that can supply a transformer for *any* input type, given the fixed output type? (I suspect the real answer is to replace your enum values with types, but you'll have to clarify at which point you learn what the types are).

Comment: I suppose i'm going in a bit of a circle. Here's the actual scenario: The request comes in via HTTP with those enums as request parameters and the output is once again untyped. However, the pipeline to go from inputs to outputs is constructed from several similar shaped pieces conveying and converting different types. The construction of that pipeline currently is manual and repetitive, and could be a lot more concise, except that wiring of types gets in the way. Not sure if that's anymore clear. I may write up a new question with the problem instead of my non-functioning solution

Comment: Typeclasses are resolved at compile time, so I think there's no way to avoid writing a `case` for each of your MxN `Transformer` instances explicitly. Once you're doing that (e.g. by matching both enums at once) the problem goes away, right? But yeah, it means writing a line for every possible combination (or else doing horrible hacks like constructing a class name through string manipulation), which is tedious.

Comment: Ho hum.. That's the solution i have in place. A giant case statement enumerating all enum combinations and specifying the components and then, yes, the problem goes away since each of those calls has the parameters completely specified.

Comment: Note, the above comments are based on the original sample code. I've simplified to remove the red herring of enums and clarify the question about typeclasses and generic parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `fun1` like this.

```
def fun1[A](a: A)(implicit converter: Converter[A, Int]) = fun2(a, 42)
```

In Scala, the type inference does not "flow backwards", only from left to right and top to bottom. So, the usage of `fun1(1)` is not considered for the implicit resolution for `fun1` – it does not fix `A` to an `Int`. Seeing only the function definition by its own, the compiler knows nothing about `A` when it tries to find the `Converter[A, B]` for `fun2`. It knows, that `B` must `b` an Int, but at this point, `A` could be anything. So, you'll have to provide the compiler with the proper type class it can use: `(implicit converter: Converter[A, Int])`. Now, when calling `fun1(1)`, the compiler knows about `A` and can look for a `Converter[Int, Int]`.